# Testing a website fonts

Tags: fonts

How can I be sure that the fonts I've used/installed on a website are showing correctly on every display?

For example, on my latest project I've used "BrandonGrotesque" font. I've added to CSS. The location of the fonts is ok. I've tested the site on my mobile, and it looks good, but when I've open the site on a computer that dosen't have this font installed, I was getting some serif font.

How can I check if the fonts are showing correctly?

Comment: Ironically, it is on topic to ask how to test something, but not to ask for recommendations of services to test something, so I've slightly edited your question to avoid this pitfall.

Answer (score 0):

> are showing correctly on every display.

You cannot. No matter what you simply cannot. Client can block external resources, certain types of data whatever. You simply cannot assume anything on environment you control. Still, this is pretty common for many things so it's best to **ensure** you are safe, than assume you are. If you can check certain asset is available or not - do it and warn the user if something is missing. But unless you control the target environment in 100% you should assume you failed rather you succeded - that'd ironcally make your app better 
:)